# Why does jQuery Mobile add in divs, classes etc

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've been working on a small site and now I want to add a switch using jQuery mobile since it needs to work well on mobile devices. But when I add the necessary files it messes up my whole mark up by adding divs around input files. Adding classes to the body and divs, and adding styling to the div's and classes which destroy my whole layout.

What's the point of that? This makes me not want to use jQuery Mobile since now I have to write exceptions everywhere :/

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: JQM is a framework. You should have started developing from ground with it.

Comment: you can create a custom jQM framework by including any widget you want, and initialize them manually.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté so if you have an excisiting website and want to use a few things from the jQuery Mobile framework you have to rebuild everything? Looks like a waste of time.

Comment: @Omar I did this, I only included the switch part I need, but then the module doesn't work.

Comment: have you used http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ ?

Comment: @Omar yes I did, I only added the "Flip Switch" module, since I need that. But when I use the custom css/js files the module doesn't work. When I use the full download it does work.

Comment: You need to initialize it on `.ready()` this way: `$('selector').flipswitch();` if you're using JQM 1.4 custom build.

Comment: @Omar I'm using the **Basic checkbox switch checked** function from [JQM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/flipswitch/)

On the [Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) I only select "Flip switch" and extract the files into my workspace. 

**FlipSwitch**
`%form
    %label{:for => "flip-checkbox"}Flip toggle switch checkbox:
    %input{:type => "checkbox", :"data-role" => "flipswitch", :name => "flip-checkbox", :id => "flip-checkbox", :checked => ""}`

**jQuery**
`$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('selector').flipswitch();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a [custom jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/), links in head should be placed as follows:

```
<!-- structure for custom themes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css"/>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- load jQM after jQuery -->
<script src="jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
```

And then, you need to initialize widgets, each widget has its own function.

```
$(function () {
  $("#flip-checkbox-ID").flipswitch(); /* initialize flip-switch*/
});
```